# Lilypond : Adding lyrics into backslash temporary voices

Tags: lilypond

I'm pretty new when it comes to details on Lilypond and I'm stuck on a problem.
Whenever I introduce two new temporary voices with backslash `<<{ }\\\\{ }>>`, the lyrics skip over those voices :

```
Lyrics = \lyricmode {Et lux per -- pe -- tu -- a }
\score {
  \new ChoirStaff
  <<
  \new Voice = "soprano"
  \relative c' {
    \clef treble
    c4 f8 f
    <<{a a}\\{f f}>>
    c'4
  }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "soprano" { \Lyrics }
  >>
}
```

Here is the document: http://lilybin.com/xbi9lm/1

I've tried a lot of things, and one that does something interesting is this:

```
Lyrics = \lyricmode {Et lux per a }
LyricsTwo = \lyricmode {pe -- tu }

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff
  <<
  \new Voice = "soprano"
  \relative c' {
    \clef treble
    c4 f8 f
    <<{a a}\\{f f}\new Lyrics \lyricsto "2" {\LyricsTwo}>>
    c'4
  }
  \new Lyrics \lyricsto "soprano" { \Lyrics }
  \new Voice = "alto"
  \relative c' {
    \clef treble
    c1
  }
  >>
}
```

Here is the document : http://lilybin.com/xbi9lm/2

Using backslashes for temporary voices creates two voices named "1" and "2" so that's what I've tried, but somehow the lyrics get under the entire score ?

I use them a lot but for very short amount of notes/time.

I'm at a complete loss so if someone has a good solution for integrating lyrics into temporary multiple backslash voices, I'm all ears !

Answer (score 3):

While for keyboard music I also use the `<< { … } \\ { … } >>` notation a lot, for music with lyrics I prefer to give Lilypond one voice onto which to hang the lyrics. I leave out `\\`, and Lilypond will regard the inside of `<< … >>` as belonging to the same voice. We want only one of the two to belong, so we explicitly declare a different voice for the other.

```
Lyrics = \lyricmode { Et lux per -- pe -- tu -- a }

\score {
  \new ChoirStaff <<
    \new Voice = "soprano" \relative c' {
      \clef treble
      c4 f8 f
      <<
        { \voiceOne a a }
        \new Voice { \voiceTwo f f }
      >>
      \oneVoice c'4
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "soprano" { \Lyrics }
    \new Voice = "alto"
    \relative c' {
      \clef treble
      c1
    }
  >>
}
```

Output:

[image]

The `\voiceOne`, `\voiceTwo` and `\oneVoice` macros I call are what your double-backslash notation also calls behind the scenes to get the voices look like voice 1 and 2 (mainly the stem directions). I trust you to fix the beaming.

Comment: Thank you so much, it works !
Edit : 
So if i'm understanding correctly, the lyrics are going to stick to \voiceOne ? And then go back to \oneVoice ?

Comment: `\voiceOne` does not mean it’s a new voice, it’s still the same voice as before the `<<`. `\voiceOne` and `\oneVoice` only tells how that voice is printed. `\voiceOne` means stems up, and `\oneVoice` means stems in their neutral direction (there is a little more to it, but this suffices as explanation for now).